# Is it a good practice to define datatypes in `__init__.py`?

Tags: python, architecture, design-principles

I have a folder structure like this:

```
nlp  
├── generation  
│   ├── io_operations  
│   ├── __init__.py  
│   ├── generator.py  
│   ├── processing.py  
│   └── prompting.py  
│ ├── prompts (folder)
│ ├── ressources (folder)
│ ├── __init__.py  
│ ├── classifier.py  
│ ├── clustering.py  
│ ├── dsos.py  
│ ├── mapper.py  
│ └── utils.py
```

and in both `nlp/generation/__init__.py` and `nlp/__init__.py` I have custom datatypes defined. The datatypes in `generation` are used across the entire folder structure (so, e.g., in `classifier` something from there can be used. So it is "globally" available and easy to import by just calling `from nlp.generation import structure`. The data structures defined in `nlp/__init__.py` are not used in the `generation` sub-directory but only on that level (and sometimes from outside). Here, too, importing them is just `from nlp import structure`.

My question is whether that is a good practice or not, and if not, why. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you defining them in `__init__.py`?  Those are normally used to initialize a package, if at all.  More commonly they're just empty files.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I am asking. So something like a `datatypes.py` file would be more reasonable?